# How to display MSRP price in product listing page in magento2 through programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product, msrp

Please help me this task I don't know how to implement this task.The below screenshot is my requirement.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to get MSRP in List Page

```
 if( $_product->getMsrp()){
        $msrpPrice  = $_product->getMsrp();
    echo "<div class='price-box'>
    <span class='old-price'>
        <span class='price-container price-final_price tax weee'>
            <span class='price-label'>Retail</span>
                <span id='old-price-1'  class='price-wrapper'><span class='price'>".$this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($_product->getMsrp())."</span></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    </div>";
}
```

Comment: Hi @ Aravind, Can you please send me file path.Can you please help me.

Comment: Have you overide your catalog file in your theme??

Comment: Hi@Aravind, Your code is not working.Can you please help me?

Comment: could you post your list.phtml file you are using..

Comment: Hi @ Aravind,  This is my file path adding your code:C:\xampp7.0\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml Can you please help me?

Comment: echo $_product->getMsrp();

Comment: check whether you are getting MSRP Price..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74541/discussion-between-aravind-and-dileep-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

check below link for MSRP Price

```
 https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-minimum-advertised-price-map-in-magento-2.html
```

Comment: Hi @ Aravind,  I have followed your link but it doesn't display.Can you please help me?

Comment: MSRP price does not display in the product listing page

Comment: Hi @ Aravind,  In list.phtml file adding your code it is not working.Can you please help me?